Merge multiple rows into a single row in Azure Stream Analytics Job
In Azure Stream Analytics Job, I want to group multiple rows in to a single row. For now I was using Group By in query but some columns vlaue are setting to null. I have also verified the json input in Azure Stream Analytics.

Result will be in single row


How should the result value be?

@Aswin I have attached result image

Since all the fields are of numeric datatypes, you can use max() aggregation function for all the columns. Below is the sample code.
Code:
select
max(Active_power)  as Active_power,
max(Output_type) as output_type,
.....
from input
group  by
TumblingWindow(hour,1)



thanks @Aswin. It is working. I added multiple keys after "Group By" that were not working.

Great, you solved. You can mark this solution as answer if it helped.
